# How to design this estimator?

Tags: control, control-system, matlab

I have the following problem to solve:

[image]

I am really at loss of how to design the estimator for such a system and plot the closed loop step response. This is what I have so far in Matlab:

```
clear all; clc

A = [0 0 1 0; 0 0 0 1; 0 -9.8 -1/80 0; 0 0 0 0];
B = [0 0 1/4 100/19]';
C = [1 0 0 0];
D = 0;
model = ss(A,B,C,D)

%%
det(obsv(A,C)); % different from zero
a = charpoly(A); a = a(2:length(a))
p = poly([(-3.83+9.24i), (-3.83-9.24i), (-9.24+3.83i), (-9.24-3.83i)]); p = p(2:length(p))

Lt = p-a
Wo = obsv(A,C)
Wot = inv([1 0 0 0; a(1) 1 0 0; a(2) a(1) 1 0; a(3) a(2) a(1) 1])
L = inv(Wo)*Wot*Lt'


Kt = p-a
Wr = ctrb(A,B)
Wrt = inv([1 a(1) a(2) a(3); 0 1 a(1) a(2); 0 0 1 a(1); 0 0 0 1])
K = Kt*Wrt*inv(Wr)
kr = -1/(C*inv(A - B*K)*B)


newA = [A-B*K B*K; zeros(4,4) A-L*C]
newB = [B*kr; zeros(4,1)]
newC = [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
newD = 0

newmodel = ss(newA,newB,newC,newD)
step(newmodel)
```

I don't know if what I'm doing is right because the professor for this course hasn't really taught us how to handle such systems. Please help in any way possible. No one is giving me guidance and I am a really desperate college student trying to understand control theory concepts.

**EDIT:** I do have some knowledge of what I am doing. I know how to design control laws of the form \$u = -Kx + k_rr\$ to get state feedback, and where the new closed-loop system will be governed by the new dynamics matrix \$A - B*K\$.

Comment: This is a question from your textbook? In many courses, you are expected to read and learn from the textbook directly.

Comment: Control theory (and DSP) is **not** about pushing the right buttons in Matlab.  So the *very first thing to do* is resist the temptation to jump for the keyboard.  Can you append to your question the *feedback* you are getting from the plant, and give us your guesses as to how the dynamics of the plant are reflected in that feedback?

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I just edited my question to give more background on what I know. @TimWescott the feedback should now be clear since I have provided the form of the control law and my code computes the gain matrix K and the scalar gain \$k_r\$

Comment: What is the feedback gain from the plant?  I.e., you measure some \$y = C x\$ -- what is C?

Comment: For that matter, what is the state evolution matrix (A) and input matrix (B) for the plant.  Have you read the section of your book on observers?  If there's not an entire chapter on it, there should at least be some sections devoted to it somewhere.

Comment: I included them in my code, where I define A,B,C, and D @TimWescott

Comment: First, I'm doing this for free and I don't like trying to extract math from code -- even code that I wrote.  Second, you can write code without understanding the math you're encoding.  So, please, **write out the math, in math**.